# Functions that call functions and/or delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

Let's say I have an `Enemy` class with a couple properties and a method `AddPoints` which will add experience points to an `Enemy` object.  After a certain amount of experience points the `Level` property of the `Enemy` object will increase.

Initially I thought 'how can I make the program update the `Level` property when I don't know when the correct amount of experience points will be reached?.  This made me think of events (have to listen for the event to occur, in this case the outcome of the `LevelUp()` method) so I decided to do something like

```
   private void LevelUp()
            {
                if (ExperiencePoints > (5 * Level))
                {
                    Level++;
                }
            }
            public void AddPoints(int points)
            {

                this.ExperiencePoints += points;
                LevelUp();
            }
```

This way every time there are points added to the `Enemy` object the method will check whether or not the Level property needs to be incremented.  Having one method call another method made think about containment/delegation (one method is 'nested' inside another).  In this way, my `AddPoints` function *sort of* acts like a function pointer (at least in my mind).

Does anyone with a knowledge of language design or a good historical knowledge of C++/C# find this a helpful way of thinking about delegates?  With the following code is there any way that a delegate can improve the program, or is it too simple?

full Enemy class

```
class Enemy
    {

        public int ExperiencePoints { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


        private int level;
        public int Level
        {
            get { return level; }
            private set { level = value; }
        }

        private void LevelUp()
        {
            if (ExperiencePoints > (5 * Level))
            {
                Level++;
            }
        }
        public void AddPoints(int points)
        {

            this.ExperiencePoints += points;
            LevelUp();
        }

        public Enemy()
        {
            ExperiencePoints = 1;
            Level = 1;
        }
    }
```

testing

```
delegate void myDelegate(int x);
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Enemy e = new Enemy();
            myDelegate del = e.AddPoints;
            e.AddPoints(10); //Level =1 at runtime, after this call Level=2
            del(20);//now Level=3
            Console.WriteLine(e.Level);//output = 3


        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your question to do with the delegates, or how to handle the `LevelUp` functionality? It's hard to determine what your *exact* question is.

Comment: "or is it too simple?" Simple is beautiful and is best. Don't add complexity just for the sake of it. Don't use delegates unless you know why, how and are forced to use one.

Comment: A better way to phrase it would be: is one function calling another function in any way similar internally to using delegates

Comment: get some understanding of delegates. Delegates are intended to do much more than just one function calling another.

Comment: The first solution you gave is the best solution. But make Experience a `{ get; private set; }` so one can add experience ONLY using `AddPoints`